# ASP.NET MVC TDD (xUnit) - failing ConfigurationManager.AppSettings for no reason

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, appsettings, configurationmanager, xunit

I am trying to get familiar with TDD concept and wrote a first test that its "act" part looks like this:

```
repositoryStub = new Mock<IMyRepository>();
var sut = new MyController(repositoryStub.Object);
var result = sut.Index() as ViewResult;
```

The controller (`MyController`) that I am instantiating eventually (deep down) uses `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, while creating view model. The instantiation of the controller fails on the line that is trying to read from Web.Config, but, obviously, runs as expected if project is just run from IDE.
I am reading a constant from web.config file, which should not affect the test and it wasn't expected that it will fail once called from another (`MyProject.Test`) project.

My question to you guys is how to overcome this obstacle?

I don't know if it matters here, but just in case, I am using `xUnit` for TDD.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that configuration you're using *deep down* is the same kind of dependency as `IMyRepository`. You inject repository via abstract contract (interface). Why the same isn't done for configuration? Quick and naive solution would be to create `IConfiguration` interface and implement it by simply delegating calls to `ConfigurationManager`. Your constructor would look like this:

```
public class MyController(IMyRepository repository, IConfiguration configuration)
```

What does that tell us? Well, not much unfortunately. Fact that controller requires configuration is very vague. Real question is, what's the **exact** parameter from configuration it needs? You need to identify that very parameter and that's the real dependency you want to inject. Consider:

- `MyController(IMyRepository repository, IConfiguration configuration)`
- `MyController(IMyRepository repository, int serviceCallTimeoutSeconds)`
- `MyController(IMyRepository repository, string serviceAccessKey)`

Which one communicates its purpose better? The more single-feature oriented your controller is, the less parameters it should use. Your problem might not be where you think it is.

Comment: @JimmyKeen Thank you very much for the comprehensive response. The configuration I am using is rather trivial, its static file keeping all (most) project constants. I do agree that controller should use least amount of settings to be able to operate, but part of its aim is to create profile, which contains an image (logo), and the constant in this case is its location and file name. I hate to hard code this stuff and had externalized it. Doesn't seem to me it require Interface abstraction, its just a constant ... What do you think? And how to approach this problem? Move it to view model? 10x!

Comment: @DisplayName: yes, it's best to externalize it. This way you can simply set it in `web.config` (this is where such stuff belongs to). Having it hard coded in controller code causes issues you got now (testing) and hides this important fact (dependency) from other developers. Simply add it via constructor injection, just as you would do with any other dependency.

Comment: @JimmyKeen Thanks very much! Let me ask you this then: I started working on defining IConfig etc and came to conclusion that this is a bit ridiculous: `public static class Config` is **static** (keeping all constants for the project). Do you think all of the above is still valid considering its static?

Comment: @DisplayName: You don't need `IConfig` parameter, you need `string logoFilePath` (or `directory` + `fileName` combination). Don't think of your logo file path as constant - it's controller's dependency. Its source is irrelevant here, what's important is that controller has it provided from composition root (place where you wire-up your container and dependencies).